# Show pdf folder with its content to user

Tags: java, android

I have an app that save some pdf files in sdcard/android/data/com.myapp/files/pdf. I'd like to show its content to user, so he/she can open the pdfs, read it using another app, share...

This is my code to create the folder:

```
        File folder = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(MainActivity.this
                .getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "pdf");
```

SO, I'd like to open this folder to the user, because it is quite a hard task to open it all manually. Any ideas how can I do it in any android api version?

Comment: Sorry, but there is no concept in Android of "open this folder to the user".

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your answer! So I am saving it in the wrong place? Any ideas what I can do to show this pdfs to user?

Comment: Just list the files and show them in a list view. `folder.listFiles()`.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for your answer! I'm trying to open the pdf after save, the problem is some users don't got a pdf reader... I will also create a list view in another activity as you mention so user can click to open the pdf he wants to read. I thought it would be easier to just open the pdf folder...

Comment: "So I am saving it in the wrong place?" -- it is OK. However, on Android 11+, other apps have no access to it, unless you make the content available via `FileProvider`. And, Android has no "open this folder" operation for arbitrary filesystem directories. Perhaps, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and let the user choose where on the user's device you should be storing the user's PDFs.

Comment: `the problem is some users don't got a pdf reader..` No, that is not your problem.